# How to wait for callback result before continuing the loop in Javascript Cordova iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, callback

I have the cordova file plugin and i want to copy images to tmp folder of the app to load it into the wkwebview. But whenever i try to loop the copy function for each image, the loop does not wait for the callback to process. The callback only gets called once at the end of the loop i.e if i have to display 3 images, the function only returns callback for one image.

```
//loop
for(var i = 0; i > imagesPath.length; i++){
   getTempPathForImage(imagesPath[i], function(result){
      //display image
   });
}

//the function that gets called
//"/" is the destination i.e root path of tmp directory
function getTempPathForImage(filePath,onSuccess){ 
   moveFile(filePath, "/", function (tempImage) {
      onSuccess(tempImage);
   });
}
```

I want to make it so that the loop waits each time for the callback result. Also, i cant change the moveFile function because it is a built-in function of cordova file plugin that works only with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your loop condition.

it should be

```js
for(var i = 0; i < imagesPath.length; i++){
   getTempPathForImage(imagesPath[i], function(result){
      //display image
   });
}
```

to wait for the callback you can wrap your function into async

Please refer to this link for an example

https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/